# Dual processor: is the memory shared?

Tags: memory, cpu

I was browsing the system76 page for servers https://www.system76.com/servers/model/jacp8 and i realized that when u check the option for a second processor you must choose memory for that processor. In dual processor systems, does the memory get shared? In my old powermac g4 with 2 processors i remember they are shared.

Comment: Considering that a XEON processor only is able to access 4 channels of memory: http://ark.intel.com/products/64596/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2690-20M-Cache-2_90-GHz-8_00-GTs-Intel-QPI its not clear how they are even offering ( 12 x 16GB ) options.  I suggest you just contact SYstem76 to answer this question.

Comment: 4 channels != 4 DIMMs.  The motherboard image shows 12 DIMMs per socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple socket systems that do not share memory (along with cache coherence) are relatively exotic ([Calxeda's EnergyCard](http://www.calxeda.com/technology/products/energycards/quadnode/) is an example) and System76 is more of a whitebox vendor than a specialized system designer.  The use of 2xxx versions indicates System76 are paying Intel for support of cache coherence and memory sharing, so it is *very* unlikely that they would be using them in some kind of mini-cluster-on-a-motherboard design.

Comment: So would a multithreade program only be able to run on one processor?

Comment: For a traditional system like the System76 example, threads can be distributed across multiple sockets.  (The performance impact of thread distribution is a complex subject, but for only two sockets with a modern OS such considerations are usually not significant.)

Comment: Where would the programs memory be stored? Will the contents of the program in ram be transferred over?

Comment: @agovizer For a 2 socket system the difference in latency and bandwidth for remote (alternative socket) memory is not that great, but modern NUMA-aware OSes will tend to map memory according to locality of use so less than half of the accesses should be remote.  Other than the access being a *little* slower, it does not really matter much where the memory is mapped; the content will be transfered in cache line sized (64B) chunks from (local or remote) memory to the local cache as it is accessed.